# Error deploying Go apps to Google App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, gcloud, google-cloud-sdk

When I run `gcloud app deploy` to deploy my Go application, I get the following error message:

```
"Please verify that you have execute permission for allfiles in your CLOUD SDK bin folder"
```

How do I resolve it?

Answer (score 5):

This is due to an issue with the Cloud SDK 160.0.0 release. The bad release has been rolled back. Run:

```
gcloud components update
```

and try again.